# js get event from button in dynamic modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i try to get the `click` event from an button in an bootstrap Modal, that was created throw js.

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="myModal_4an2nk" role="dialog" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button><h4   class="modal-title">Löschen bestätigen</h4>    
            </div> 
            <div class="modal-body"> 
                <p>Möchten Sie den Datenstatz wirklich löschen?.</p>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button> 
               <button class="btn btn-danger removeEntryConfirm" data-dismiss="modal" id="583">Löschen</button>
           </div> 
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This modal are added per jquery to my Html. no i try to get the the click on the `.removeEntryConfirm` Button.

```
$(document).on('click','#removeEntryConfirm',function(e){
    //do something
});
```

why is the event not trigert?

**UPDATED**

```
<button class="btn btn-danger removeEntryConfirm" data-dismiss="modal" id="583">Löschen</button>
$(document).on('click','.removeEntryConfirm',function(e){

});
```

working

Comment: `removeEntryConfirm` is a class use `.`

Comment: I don't find any id with specified name. But here is a class that should be selected using . Instead of #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.` to select classes. `removeEntryConfirm` is a class not an `ID`

Try This:

```
$(document).on('click','.removeEntryConfirm',function(e){
 //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"#removeEntryConfirm" should be ".removeEntryConfirm" in javascript code.

You should use '#' prefix if you want to select elements with id attribute, you should use '.' prefix if you want to select elements with class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

@Guradio is right, you're using an ID selector 
    `$('#some_id')...`
when you should be using a class selector 
    `$('.some_class')...`
For the element you're targeting.

Also, note that if you're adding the markup for the modal to the page with JavaScript, make sure that you add the click handler *after* the element you're targeting has been added because if you add it before, the selector won't find anything and it won't do anything.